# Host Silverlight in IFrame & Enterprise Mode

Tags: html, .net, silverlight, microsoft-edge

I need to display some legacy Silverlight (OHH-YEAAH!) widgets on a modern website.

Using Edge77 +  Enterprise Mode Site List it is possible to force specific sites into IE Mode.

However, I have trouble getting this to work within an IFrame:

Basically I want to do something like this:

```
<div>

   Chrome Mode

   // IE-MODE
  <iframe src="https://www.silverlight-legacy.com" width="640" height="480">
  </iframe>

   Chrome Mode
</div>
```

Any advice how to get this working?

Comment: You can only do this on windows. I will make an answer about how to do this in a little though :)

Comment: I think it's impossible to use IE 11 Enterprise Mode only in iframe. The view mode will always be set according to the topmost frame/window even if you set the iframe in Enterprise Mode Site List. I think the only way is to set the whole website into IE mode.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know: Microsoft Silverlight will reach the end of support on October 12, 2021. Use this time, to port the app to something else.